# TCP connections behind NAT

Tags: java, networking, tcp, vert.x

```
 __________                                 __________
|          |>------->TCP Request>-----X NAT|          |
| Server 1 |                               | Server 2 |
|__________|✔-------<TCP Request<------<NAT|__________|
```

In java using Vertx I have two nodes that are both sending messages to each other over the EventBus but the one behind the NAT cannot receive messages. So I made a TCP client and server to mimic the environment and got the same behavior. I discovered that by forwarding the TCP port on Server 2 firewall it can now send and receive messages, but this will only work for one machine.

Is it possible to have more dynamic method to get this working, is it possible to set-up UPnP in Java so the connection is routed?

Comment: A Google search for java + upnp returned tons of results.  Have any of those been of help?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have tried the library at [link](https://github.com/offbynull/portmapper) and it seems to be working. I was asking if UPnP would fix the issue I was having.